# 'JAVA_HOME is not set' error while installing pig. What to do about it?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I followed all the steps on pig.apache.org ,but not able to remove this error by setting java variable. I set the variable earlier while installing java jdk but its asking again for the variable.

Comment: Please provide more info: how you set the variable, what text is in the log file.

Comment: Thanks sir, next time ,will definitely do that. I'm sorry , I'm new at this, but catching up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are installing PIG on ubuntu do this

open bashrc file using below command and and lines to the end of the file

```
vi ~/.bashrc
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386
```

then log out or Restart your system and try again.

For CentOS

Create a new file called java.sh

```
    vim /etc/profile.d/java.sh
```

Within this file, initialize the necessary environment variables

```
    export JRE_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_12/jre
    export PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin

    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_12
    export JAVA_PATH=$JAVA_HOME

    export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Replace java path with your java installation.
[Source](http://blogs.alliedtechnique.com/2009/04/16/setting-global-environment-variables-in-centos/)

Comment: 1) It is JAVA_HOME not PIG_HOME.  2) You are assuming a particular JDK install dir.  What if he is using 64 bit?  Java 7?  Oracle rather than OpenJDK?  3) You don't need to restart the system to restart the user's interactive shell sessions.  Just logging out and in should be sufficient.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for feedback it was a typo and yeah log out should be sufficient

Comment: I matched my export commands with yours, and they matched, it was just that i had not sourced the profile..

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand how environment variables work in Linux (or Windows).

The chances are that you only set JAVA_HOME temporarily in the shell that you used to do the installation.  To set JAVA_HOME permanently (on Linux / UNIX) you need to set it in a shell "rc" file that gets run each time a new shell is created.  (It depends on which shell you are using, but `man` can tell you about that ...)

Answer (score 0):

To set your JAVA_HOME variable for your current shell, use the `export` command.  This will immediately create an environment variable for JAVA_HOME, but the variable is lost when your shell is closed.

`export JAVA_HOME=<path_to_java_sdk>`

The best way to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable for Pig and Hadoop use is by adding it to your local rc file.  The reason for this is that some distributions of Hadoop (Cloudera, Hortonworks, MapR) may include their own Java installation for the Hadoop application itself.  You may not want to create a global environment variable, since it may interfere with Hadoop/Hive/etc.

To have the variable set for individual Hadoop/Pig users on the server, they need to run the following command:

`echo "export JAVA_HOME=<path_to_java_sdk>" >> ~/.bashrc`

Afterward executing the command, they can `source ~/.bashrc` to instantiate the environment variable.

Comment: I've added ' export JAVA_HOME = <path>' in the .bash_profile , but still it shows java_home is not set while typing , pig command in terminal. What to do?

Comment: If you've added it to your profile, then you need to source the profile before you can use the variable.  `source ~/.bash_profile`